# dropdown from 2 tables in database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to create a form to add a club in my database.
To do that i need a form with 4 labels. 3 of them are in the database "clubes" but 1 of the labels is a dropdown that i need the rows from another table ("professores"), they have a foreign key ("ID_Professor")
At this momment i dont have any error but also, the dropdown is empty

**MODEL:**

```
public function getdepartment() {
  $query = $this->db->select('ID_Professor')->from('clubes')->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function clubes_lista() {
        $data['clubes'] = 'clubes';
        $this->load->model('clubesModel');
        $data['clubes'] = $this->base_model->getCourseAll();
        $data['clubes'] = $this->base_model->getdepartment();
        $this->load->view('clubes', $data);
    }
```

**VIEW:**

```
<select name="ID_Profesor" class="form-control">
      <?php foreach($clubes as $row) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row->clubes.'">'.$row->clubes.'</option>';
        } ?>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must make clear your question, but I try to answer your question. For example, if you need to select from two tables from two models,

controller

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('clubesModel');
    $this->load->model('anotherModel');
}

public function clubes_lista() 
 {
$dataclubes = $this->anotherModel->getCourseAll();
$dataprofesor = $this->clubesModel->getdepartment();
$data = array(
        'dataclubes' => $dataclubes,
        'dataprofesor' => $dataprofesor,
    );
    $this->load->view('clubes', $data);
 }
```

view

```
<select class="form-control col-md-3"  name="w">
                <option value="all">Clubes</option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($dataclubes as $value) { ?>
                    <option value="<?= $value->id_profesor?>"><?= $value->fieldview?> 
                        </option>
                <?php        
                    }
                ?>
                     <?php
                     foreach ($dataclubes as $value) { ?>
                    <option value="<?= $value->id_another?>"><?= $value->fieldview?> 
                     </option>
                        <?php        
                        }

                    ?>
            </select>
```